# How can I retrieve the input from the custom field on the product table page and pass it to the cart page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I've created a product table list for my project and added a custom field to allow users to input their own values. Unfortunately, while the custom field works on the product page, it doesn't seem to work on my second function where I call the product table. I've been struggling to find a solution to retrieve the input from the custom field and pass it to the cart page, which is what a custom field typically does.

Here my first and second function that I use

First function for custom field

```
// Add custom field to WooCommerce product page
function add_custom_field_to_product() {
    global $product;

    // Display the custom field label and input
    echo '<div class="custom-field" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">';
    echo '<label for="custom_field">Message:</label>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<input type="text" id="custom_field" name="custom_field" value="' . esc_attr(get_post_meta($product->get_id(), 'custom_field', true)) . '">';
    echo '</div>';
}

// Save custom field value
function save_custom_field_value($cart_item_data, $product_id) {
    if (isset($_POST['custom_field'])) {
        $custom_field_value = sanitize_text_field($_POST['custom_field']);
        $cart_item_data['custom_field'] = $custom_field_value;
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_custom_field_value', 10, 2);

// Display custom field value in cart
function display_custom_field_in_cart($item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key) {
    if (isset($cart_item['custom_field'])) {
        $custom_field_value = $cart_item['custom_field'];
        if ($custom_field_value) {
            $item_name .= '<br><span class="custom-field-value"><strong>Message:</strong> ' . $custom_field_value . '</span>';
        }
    }
    return $item_name;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'display_custom_field_in_cart', 10, 3);

// Hook into WooCommerce product page display
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_custom_field_to_product');
```

Second function to list my product

```
// Function to retrieve and display all WooCommerce products in a vertical table with category titles
function display_woocommerce_products_table($product_id) {
    $output = '';

    // Retrieve all child product categories from WooCommerce
    $parent_categories = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'parent' => 0,
    ));

    // Get the currency symbol from WooCommerce settings
    $currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();

    // Loop through each parent category
    foreach ($parent_categories as $parent_category) {
        $child_categories = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'parent' => $parent_category->term_id,
        ));

        // Loop through each child category of the current parent category
        foreach ($child_categories as $child_category) {
            // Retrieve all products in the current child category, sorted by price (high to low)
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        'terms' => $child_category->term_id,
                    ),
                ),
                'meta_key' => '_price',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                'order' => 'DESC',
            );
            $products = new WP_Query($args);

            if ($products->have_posts()) {
                $output .= '<h2>' . $child_category->name . '</h2>'; // Add category title

                // Add category description if available
                if (!empty($child_category->description)) {
                    $output .= '<p>' . $child_category->description . '</p>';
                }

                $output .= '<table>';

                while ($products->have_posts()) {
                    $products->the_post();
                    global $product;

                    // Get product details
                    $product_id = $product->get_id();
                    $product_name = $product->get_name();
                    $product_price = $product->get_price(); // Get raw price without formatting
                    $product_description = $product->get_short_description(); // Get short description

                    // Check if currency symbol is already present in the price
                    if (strpos($product_price, $currency_symbol) === false) {
                        $product_price = $currency_symbol . ' ' . $product_price; // Add currency symbol
                    }

                    // Modify the output of the second function to include the custom field and form
                    ob_start();
                    add_custom_field_to_product($product_id);
                    $custom_field_output = ob_get_clean();

                    // Add product details and custom field to the table
                    $output .= '<tr>';
                    $output .= '<td style="width: 150px;">'; // Set the fixed width of the first <td> to 175px
                    $output .= $product->get_image(array(150, 150)); // Thumbnail size adjusted to 150x150 pixels
                    $output .= '</td>';
                    $output .= '<td>';
                    $output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink($product_id) . '">' . $product_name . '</a><br>';
                    $output .= '<p>' . $product_description . '</p>'; // Add short description
                    $output .= $product_price;
                    $output .= '<br>';
                    $output .= $custom_field_output; // Add custom field and form

                    // Only display the add to cart form if the current product ID matches the specified product ID
                    if ($product_id == $product_id) {
                        $output .= '<form class="cart" action="' . esc_url($product->add_to_cart_url()) . '" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
                        $output .= '<div class="quantity">';
                        $output .= '<input type="number" name="quantity" class="input-text qty text" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" min="1" max="" step="1" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="off">';
                        $output .= '<span class="suki-qty-increment suki-qty-minus" role="button" tabindex="0">-</span>';
                        $output .= '<span class="suki-qty-increment suki-qty-plus" role="button" tabindex="0">+</span>';
                        $output .= '</div>';
                        $output .= '<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="' . esc_attr($product_id) . '">Buy</button>';
                        $output .= '</form>';
                    }

                    $output .= '</td>';
                    $output .= '</tr>';
                }

                $output .= '</table>';
                $output .= '<br>';

                wp_reset_postdata();
            }
        }
    }

    return $output;
}

// Shortcode for displaying the WooCommerce products table
function woocommerce_products_table_shortcode($atts) {
    $product_id = isset($atts['product_id']) ? absint($atts['product_id']) : 0;
    return display_woocommerce_products_table($product_id);
}
add_shortcode('woocommerce_products_table', 'woocommerce_products_table_shortcode');
```